# How to keep track of user attempts of invalid login, when siteminder handles user authentication

Tags: jakarta-ee, webserver, siteminder, appserver

In my project we have different siteminder team, which helps to install and configure siteminder set-up on web-server. 
Now my application requirement is we should lock user for 15 minutes, if he tries to enter invalid login credentials  5 times.
But issue is user is routed to my application (App server), only if he has been authenticated by siteminder.
Siteminder is unbale to handle this temporary lockout. If user enter invalid credentials 5 times and then closes browser. Try login in new browser with valid login, he is authenticated. So can I find invalid attempts for user when he is authenticated for my application.
How to do this? How can I find Siteminder response and keep track of user invalid attempts. or is there any other way for this?

Comment: if u use iis web server u can enable logging then get it at "%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles"

Comment: I believe the SM Advanced Password Services (https://wiki.ca.com/display/sm1252sp1/APS+Introduced) module from CA will allow this. Also, if you are using an LDAP User Store, many of them will "lock" the user account for X minutes after Y number of unsuccessful login attempts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using password policy in Siteminder this can be easily configured along with the grace attempt allowed after specified number of minutes. This is possible even if the Advanced Password Services module is not being used already. 
You may want to check with your SiteMinder folks what password services are being used and decide on how to proceed based on that. Your requirement should be manageable even if APS is not in use.